# Django: how to save model instance after deleting a ForeignKey-related instance?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am using Django 2.1.1.

I have a model `Analysis` that, among other fields, contains a ForeignKey to a `MyFile` model (a model I wrote to handle files):

```
from polymorphic.models import PolymorphicModel
from django.db.models import Model, DateTimeField, FileField, SET_NULL
from django.db.models.signals import pre_delete

class MyFile(Model):
    file = FileField(upload_to='./', null=False, blank=False)
    description = CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    date_added = DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


@receiver(pre_delete, sender=MyFile)
def mymodel_delete(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    """
    To delete the file connected to the `sender` class: receive the pre_delete signal
    and delete the file associated with the model instance.
    """
    instance.file.delete(False)

class Analysis(PolymorphicModel):
        # ... other fields ...
        file_results = ForeignKey(MyFile, on_delete=SET_NULL,
                                  related_name='file_results', 
                                  null=True, blank=True)
```

`Analysis` is a `PolymorphicModel` for reasons related to the bigger project.

In `Analysis.file_results` I set `on_delete=SET_NULL` because I want to allow an `Analysis` instance to exist even without a `file_result`, which can be populated later.

Let's suppose I have added a few files (the `MyFile` table has a few rows) and a few `Analysis` instances. Now, if I want to delete the file related to one of the instances of `Analysis` I do:

```
a = Analysis.objects.get(pk=0)
a.file_results.delete()
a.save()
```

but I get the following error:

```
File "/Users/mtazzari/djangos/views.py" in update_job_refs
  377.             a.save()

File "/Users/mtazzari/anaconda/envs/djangos/lib/python3.6/site-packages/polymorphic/models.py" in save
  83.         return super(PolymorphicModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/mtazzari/anaconda/envs/djangos/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  670.                         "unsaved related object '%s'." % field.name
ValueError: save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved
            related object 'file_results'.
```

The `mymodel_delete` function that is called on `pre_delete` signal works correctly as the file gets actually deleted from the file system.
However, I really **don't understand how to solve the `ValueError`**.

Interestingly, I notice that the following lines work fine, i.e. do not raise any ValueError, get the file deleted from the file system, and the FK in `a.file_results` set to Null:

```
a = Analysis.objects.get(pk=0)
tmp = a.file_results
a.file_results = None    
tmp.file_results.delete()
a.save()
```

But, is this a **proper way** of doing this? What is the **best practice** for deleting a related object?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, note that you don't need to `save()` just because of the `delete()`. The `delete()` will update the database as required.

That said, it's reasonable to want to continue using the instance to do other operations, leading to a `save()`. The reason you're getting the error is that the `a.file_results` Python object still exists, and references a database row that is now missing. The [documentation for `delete()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.delete) mentions this:

> This only deletes the object in the database; the Python instance will still exist and will still have data in its fields.

So if you want to continue to work with the instance object, just set the attribute to `None` yourself. Similar to your code above, except you don't need the temp object.

```
a = Analysis.objects.get(pk=0)
a.file_results.delete()
a.file_results = None

# ... more operations on a

a.save()  # no error
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I read that sentence in the docs before but I find it quite obscure anyway as it doesn't say what to do with the Python instance, whether it is fine to forget about it or not. Your solution works. Given that the Python instance is not strictly valid anymore, I'd expect the `a.file_results=None` could be added inside the `.delete()` method by default.

Comment: @mtazzari: The `MyFile.delete()` method doesn't know anything about `a`, or any of the other names that might point to it. Think about doing `a.delete()`: should the `a` name simply disappear from the scope? Python just doesn't work like that.